# MySQL datediff lag over partition by failing

Tags: mysql, sql, partitioning, lag, datediff

[attached shows error displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/si7Zo.png)

I am currently working on what will ultimately be using the generated number of days from the query below to update a table. Currently I am focusing on the select portion for my data. The end goal is to calculate the days between when a SN was last returned for repair. I originally built this query inside of SSMS and have a working product in that environment. However the end user is using MySQL and the query does not work for them.
I do see an error on my end after downloading MySQL workbench that states

> ""(" is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting
> FOR, LOCK, SELECT, TABLE, VALUES, WITH" this error is shown for the (
> on the "(partition" portion below.

Any help is appreciated.

```
Select Serial_Number, 
       Receive_Date,
       datediff( Receive_Date, lag(Receive_Date,1) OVER(partition by Serial_Number order by Receive_Date asc)) as days_between_test
from QA_Combined_Data_test;
```

Comment: What is the mysql version being used? Window functions are supportly only in version 8+. would `MSSM` actually be `SSMS` ie Sql Server Management Studio...?

Comment: mysql 8.0

Yes, I was intending SSMS, my apologies. I need to proofread before posting better.

Comment: There must be something you're omitting from your question as your query as written [has no such error](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=87eb293c3fb396ed9d0adecc608d2fae)

Comment: I added an image of what I am seeing. I have also verified I am on 8.0.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, as you can see from the link in the previous comment; you need to add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Possibly an SSMS error, not MySQL?